# Problema no caminho do CSS e JS em projeto MVC

Tags: php

Estou construindo uma aplicação php com MVC, o problema é ao acessar outros diretórios pela URL, Ex: mvc/user (até aqui tudo certo) agora: mvc/user/**create** (aqui a folha de estilos css e o javascript já não são mais encontrados) , qual a melhor forma de consertar isso? definir uma constante ou configurar o htaccess?

#### Estrutura

```
-controllers/ 
-lib/ 
-public/ 
   --css/ 
   --js/ 
   --images/
-models/ 
-views/ 
   --Index/ 
   --Create/ ... 
   Header.phtml
   Footer.phtml
```

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Tudo bem simples.

Comment: Usando algum framework? Poderia mostrar como está a estrutura de diretórios?

Comment: Não, estou fazendo a mão mesmo, pra estudar.
aqui a estrutura:
-controllers/
-lib/
-public/
**--css/**
**--js/**
**--images/**
-models/
-views/
**--Index/**
**--Create/**
...

Comment: Como está o script do .htaccess que faz os redirecionamentos? Edite sua pergunta com as respostas que colocou aqui nos comentários.

Answer (score 3):

Você provavelmente está usando caminhos relativos para fazer referência para os arquivos CSS e JS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/file.css">
```

O ideal é não usar caminhos relativos para esses arquivos.

Exemplo:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/css/file.css">
```

A barra no início do caminho para o arquivo CSS acima, indica que o caminho é relativo à raiz do site, e não ao endereço que estiver na barra de endereço do navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você é familiarizado com o conceito de **View Helpers**, se não, dê uma pesquisada por aí.

O que eu costumo fazer é criar um helper que me ajuda a resolver os caminhos para esses recursos (assets):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $this->asset('/css/file.css');">
```

Em algum arquivo de configuração eu faço assim:

```
[view]
helpers.asset.base_dir=/path/to/assets
```

Dessa forma você não fica dependente de uma hierarquia de diretórios.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor que esta é a estrutura do seu site:

```
/principal
  /css
  /img
  /js
/blog
```

Se você deseja carregar uma folha de estilo a partir do diretório blog, basta você carregar da seguinte forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="principal/css/main.css" />
```

Porém, se alguém está no diretório blog/05/04/2014 esta URL irá apontar para: blog/05/04/2013/principal/css e não é esse o diretório que queremos. Para carregar independente de qualquer diretório (se o diretório principal e blog estiverem na raiz do site) basta carregar da seguinte maneira:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/principal/css/main.css" />
```

Ou no seu caso:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/arquivo.css" />
```

Basta aplicar isto também na sua tag script e ser feliz.

Answer (score 0):

Definir uma constante, o ideal é criar uma variável no seu arquivo de configuração do MVC, com um nome Domínio por exemplo e usar esta variável no início de todos os seus arquivos. Isso é o ideal na minha opinião pois serve para todos os seus arquivos, css, imagens, serve para MVC e para as reescritas.